# Bootstrap alert not closing with javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with my bootstrap alert not sliding up automatically.
In my default.aspx I have done the following:

1) Put links to js and bootstrap in head (tried different versions and links, also putting them before the closing body tag):

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
```

2) Put following script in head:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
$(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
    $(this).remove(); 
});
}, 4000);
```

3) Running this in body :

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> 
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<strong>Success!</strong> You have been signed in successfully!
</div>
```

This working.
I've tried an even later version of js as well as Bootstrap, but it still doesn't work - The alert just doesn't slide!

As you can see it works PERFECTLY here: https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/XJoLmN

So why doesn't it work in my project?

Other things I've tried are clearing cache and different browser.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: do you have only one object with class alert in the body at the time of execution?

Answer (score 0):

You can check Timeout function is called and console log $(this) variable then check any error or inconsistent their

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
console.log("Timeout");
$(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).remove(); 
});
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> 
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<strong>Success!</strong> You have been signed in successfully!
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be called at all, since I can only see the "Timeout" logged in JavaScript console. This is really strange...

Comment: Can you pleace check div's `class="alert alert-success"`?

Comment: Nothing seems strange there.. https://i.imgur.com/ZbXMvwX.png 
I must be missing something really basic, since I'm a bit of a beginner to asp.net .

Comment: can you please try $(".alert")..remove() in the console and see alert is removed or not?